QGIS flight-isochrones in mountainous terrain
I want to visualize the flight-path of a helicopter in the Austrian alps with isochrones.
As a helicopter needs a lot more time flying around mountains in a valley than it would above flat ground I wondered if there is a way in QGIS to factor in the mountains in isochrones.
I thought about assigning a certain cruise speed to the helicopter that decreases when it needs to climb depending on the terrain slope angle considering a safe height above ground.
This isochrones could for instance tell a pilot, when flying over a mountain could be faster than flying around it.
Is there a QGIS tool that does this or will I need to advance my GIS skills and program it myself?


Please decide which software you want to use.

How do you decide on the path? Is it by the mountain height? When do you decide that you can or cannot go over the mountain?

@GforGIS generally, in that area going over the mountain isn't impossible but very slow. As you climb - especially climbing steep slopes - you lose a lot of horizontal speed.
When you get below 30 to 40 knots of horizontal speed, you will lose additional lift you would otherwise gain by just flying forward.
In addition, the air gets thinner the higher you go, thus reducing your lift and by that limiting your vertical speed once again.

@GforGIS so finding the optimal flight path is always trading speed with height. That's why you have a higher difference of possible distance in a set time on even terrain.
This "trading" of speed and altitude is what makes programming this tool so difficult for me.

I assume that there is a certain formula somewhere then?

@GforGIS As aerodynamics are complicated, I would approximate it via Pythagoras for now, so the cruise speed is the square root of the sum of the horizontal/vertical speed's squares.

You might want to explore the r.walk Grass plugin for QGIS by adapting the speeds and friction factors for helicopters. See this video. Except for the involved speeds, the logic behind is the same than the one you need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OlfVa-8oKfg
